# Track Async performance using Perfume.js

Tags: javascript, typescript, performance, ecmascript-6

I have a async function where I want to use Perfume.js and track performance. like:

```
public async makeWidget(){
    const view = await makeView();
    const data = await getData();

   return { view: view, data: data }
}
```

I want to use Perfume.js library(https://zizzamia.github.io/perfume/) to track performance of this function.

Comment: What is your question? Did you read the documentation you linked?

Comment: Yes... I've gone though it. What I'm looking for is track this specific area. Since this is async, I'm not sure if it Perfume.js can track it?

Comment: I dont think it'll care whether the code between two [custom marks](https://zizzamia.github.io/perfume/#/annotate-metrics/) is async or not